# rvalue references with placement new (similar functionality to std::vector.push_back)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue, placement-new

I am implementing a container class (ObjectPool). It maintains an array of template objects in contiguous memory. On construction, it allocates a block of memory (equivalent to (size of template object)*(pool size)). When adding new objects to the pool, it uses 'placement new' operator to create an object at a specific memory address (and automatically call template object's constructor).

How do I implement the ObjectPool.add() method, to accept a template object and add it to the object pool, without calling it's constructor twice (functionality as implemented in std::vector.push_back() for example)?

For simplicity, in this case, ObjectPool class contains only one template object instead of an array.

```
class FooClass
{
public:
    FooClass(int p_testValue) : m_testValue(p_testValue)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling constructor: " << m_testValue << std::endl;
    }

    int m_testValue;
};

template <class T_Object>
class ObjectPool
{
public:
    ObjectPool()
    {
        // Allocate memory without initializing (i.e. without calling constructor)    
        m_singleObject = (T_Object*)malloc(sizeof(T_Object));
    }

    // I have tried different function arguments (rvalue reference here, amongs others)
    inline void add(T_Object &&p_object)
    {
        // Allocate the template object
        new (m_singleObject) T_Object(p_object);
    }

    T_Object *m_singleObject;
};

int main()
{
    ObjectPool<FooClass> objPool;
    objPool.add(FooClass(1));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a `T_Object&&`, that must be refering to an already-constructed `T_Object`, and then you need to create a new object in your storage, so that's another constructor call.

You need something along the lines of `emplace_back`:

```
template<class... Args>
void emplace(Args&&... args)
{
    // Allocate the template object
    ::new (static_cast<void*>(m_singleObject)) T_Object(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Call it as `objPool.emplace(1)`.

By the way, the version of `add` taking a `T_Object&& p_object` should construct the contained object from `std::move(p_object)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added _void emplace()_ method, and calling it worked perfectly. I have seen this method in the _std::vector_ container, when I was looking at _push_back_, however I did not understand the syntax completely. Is there a way to implement this, so I could call it with _(FooClass(1))_ instead of just _(1)_?

Comment: @PaulA. You can't have it both ways. `FooClass(1)` constructs a temporary `FooClass`, so overall it will call the constructor at least twice.

Comment: How does `std::vector.push_back` do it? Since, if I would call `push_back` with `FooClass(1)`, it would only call the constructor once.

Comment: @PaulA. I doubt it, unless you didn't instrument the constructors properly.